# incorrect values change (plugin gauge.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, gauge

My Gauge is made using the plugin "gauge.js" http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/
http://jsfiddle.net/aYqPT/42/

```
var opts2 = {
      lines: 1, // The number of lines to draw
      angle: 0, // The length of each line
      lineWidth: 0.15, // The line thickness
      pointer: {
        length: 0.9, // The radius of the inner circle
        strokeWidth: 0.042, // The rotation offset
        color: '#000000' // Fill color
      },
      colorStart: '#6b6b6b',   // Colors
      colorStop: '#E0E0E0',    // just experiment with them
      strokeColor: '#EEEEEE',   // to see which ones work best for you
      generateGradient: true
    };
    var target2 = document.getElementById('gauge2'); // your canvas element
    var gauge2 = new Gauge(target2).setOptions(opts2); // create gauge!
    gauge2.maxValue = 3000; // set max gauge value
    gauge2.animationSpeed = 32; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
    //gauge2.set(700); // set actual value

function getValue() {
   gauge2.set(1900);
}
setInterval(getValue, 2000);
```

Required to Gauge smoothly change from the previous value to the next.
How to make correct change value? For example, as is
http://jsfiddle.net/gliljas/gsmAL/

Thanks!